# SQL to show date for Null value based on query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables, `employee` and `employee time entry`. I have run a query that is showing me all employees with the sum of time entered or 0 as null value. In the next column I have week number. If employee has not entered time during the week than it is giving me 0 but it is also giving me null value at the week number. how can I force query to show me week number, assuming no entry was made by employee.

```
Select 
    Concat(Empfname,Emplname) as EmployeeName, 
    department,
    iif (sum(whours) is null, 0, sum(whours)) CurrentHours, 
    Datepart (ww,wdate) WeekNum
From 
    employee as e 
left outer join 
    TimeEntry as w on e.id = w.eId 
                   and wdate between '01/01/2017' and '01/31/2017' 
group by
    Concat(Empfname,Emplname), department, Datepart(ww, wdate)
```

Output

```
EmployeeName  Department  CurrentHours  WeekNum
------------------------------------------------
John Smith     Sales        8            1
Smith John     Operations   0            Null
```

How can I tell it is also from WeekNum 1?

Thanks

Comment: If the employee didn't make the entry for time, how will you know that it belongs to week1?

Comment: What week number would you like to display if no entry is made?

Comment: You can use `coalesce(Datepart (ww,wdate),1)` if you want it to be 1 incase it comes null

Comment: How about using this `SUM(COALESCE(w.hours,0)) AS CurrentHours`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select Concat(Empfname,Emplname) as EmployeeName, department
iif  (sum(whours) is null, 0, sum(whours)) CurrentHours 
ISNULL(Datepart (ww,wdate),1) WeekNum

From employee as e left outer join TimeEntry as w on e.id=w.eId 
 and wdate between '01/01/2017' and '01/31/2017' 

group by Concat(Empfname,Emplname), department, ISNULL(Datepart (ww,wdate),1)
```

which will force any `NULL` value to show `1` instead of `NULL` itself

Comment: This will work very well for week 1. What about when I go to week 20? Then this might not work.

Comment: But how could you tell which `NULL` is corresponding to which week?

Comment: That is why I am confused too. I am preparing weekly report and looking into which employee has not entered their hours. Was hoping that someone has also came across this issue and may be able to solve it.

Comment: I think first you need to know that the `NULL` comes from `Datepart(ww,wdate)`, which means the original `wdate` has invalid input for `Datepart` function, that is why you got `NULL`, so based on this, you have to get rid of or to handle the original invalid value in `wdate` using others columns to  tell which one belongs to which. If you are still confused at this point, may I know how you can tell which one belongs to week2, 3, 4 and so on based on your original table?

Comment: My apologizes for making it confusing and thank you for bearing with me.

Comment: My apologizes for making it confusing and thank you for bearing with me.  I understand that null value will show up because employee has not entered the time for the week. With left join, all employees will show up. Null will show up at hours and at week number because in Time entry table there is no value. Wild Idea: just like left join method to show all employees can I show week numbers? Any thoughts?

Comment: Try replace `between '01/01/2017' and '01/31/2017' ` to `between '20170101' and '20170131' ` to see whether the date column has been correctly treated. Your left join seems that it wont give you any `NULL` wdate

Comment: Tested: it is treating like a date. My left join is working fine too. It is giving me all employees including those who have not submitted hours.

Comment: Then for those who do not have submitted hours, how could you tell by yourself? otherwise, you cannot treat `NULL` in different ways excepting using other columns you have

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to generate all rows using `cross join` and then use `left join` to bring in the rows you want something like this:

```
Select Concat(e.Empfname, e.Emplname) as EmployeeName, e.department,
       coalesce(sum(whours), 0) as CurrentHours 
       datepart(week, wd.wdate) as WeekNum
from employee e cross join
     (select distinct wdate from TimeEntry) wd left outer join
     TimeEntry tw
     on e.id = w.eId and tw.wdate = wd.wdate
where wd.wdate between '2017-01-01' and '2017-01-31'
group by Concat(e.Empfname, e.Emplname), e.department, Datepart(week, wd.wdate);
```

Comment: This is only showing employee who have entered time. I want all the active employees from Employee table. There are also inactive employees in the table.

Comment: @Invisible . . . This should show *all* employees.  The `cross join` is based onall employees and there is no other filtering.